# How to fix error when installing libjpeg in M1 MacBook Pro?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, homebrew, arm64

I am installing libjpeg in my arm64 Terminal with the command

```
brew install libjpeg
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
```

What does it mean? and how to fix it?
Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

In terminal run this:

```
touch .zshrc
```

Open it to edit with TextEdit (It is a hidden file, so shift + command + . will unhide it)

Add this line at the end of .zshrc:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Run this in terminal to make it available:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Check to make sure it worked:

```
brew help
```